# Attacking historical ciphers methodology

Tags: classical-cipher, ciphertext-only-attack

It's more a theoretical question of how would you approach it. All you know about the ciphertext it's was generated with a historical cipher. The ciphertext appears to be random, BUT it's divided into sets of six letters. By historical ciphers I mean: mono (Ceasar), polyalphabetic (Vigenere), homophonic or polygraphic ciphers (Playfair, HillCipher).

I interested what methods would you use (Kasiski, Friedman, what else) and why and in what order to make the attack the most efficient (Friedman first?)

Comment: Do you know, for example, that the plaintext is english language? Or could be plaintext be anything?

Comment: Yes it's definitely English, only letters.

Answer (score 4):

If you don't know the system, you just check one after the other:

- frequency analysis of bigrams detects Ceasar and Playfair. Try Caesar first then Playfair.
- Auto correlation method for Vigenere (for each x: count the number of occurances, where letter at position i and i+x are equal. For the correct codeword length, it will spike)
- If you have a Hill cipher, you lost.

Comment: I'd do them in a slightly different order, just based on ease of the tasks: Caesar first, then Vigenere, then looking at bigrams for Playfair. I hope he has a lot of ciphertext if it's Playfair.

Comment: The Hill cipher [isn't exactly unbreakable](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/5066/hill-cipher-known-plaintext-attack) either. (Mind you, that question concerns a known-plaintext attack, but you could always do crib-dragging. Actually, it _might_ be possible to use frequency analysis and linear algebra for a direct ciphertext-only attack... need to think about that a bit more.)

Comment: >> If you have a Hill cipher, you lost. see this article for Hill: https://eprint.iacr.org/2015/802